# Formula appliance on data using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
344.7         2.37
346.3         2.32
347.9         2.29
349.5         2.36
351.1         2.23
352.6         2.24
354.2         2.25
355.8         2.29
357.4         2.28
358.9         2.23
```

The wavelength value are w1,w2,w3,w4,... and the reflectance values are r1,r2,r3,r4,... I wish to apply formula of r =(w2-w1)/(r2-r1) this one. The calculated value is applied as reflectance 341.6 15(ie)[r=(w2-w1)/(r2-r1)], 343.6 -7.61905(ie)[r=(w3-w2)/(r3-r2)]. I want output like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         15
343.6         -7.61905
344.7         -32
346.3         -53.3333
347.9         -53.3333
349.5         -53.3333
351.1         150
352.6         160
354.2         140
```

Is it possible in Postgresql

Comment: elaborate it more with an example. what is w1,w2,r1,r2

Comment: How do you decide on which two rows the calculation is performed?

Comment: Probably best to grab all the data and use php to sort through it row by row. Just be careful about going over the array limit.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first row" or the "second row" in a relational database unless you have something by which you can order the rows. Do you have such a column that can define an order on your results in order have something like the "first row" - if yes I think this is doable with window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you because the result differs but maybe this is useful:

```
select
wl,
(lead(wl,1) over (order by wl) - wl) /
(lead(ref,1) over (order by wl) - ref) as reflectance
from wa
order by wl
```

basically 
(wavelength[i+1] - wavelength[i]) / (reflectance[i+1] - reflectance[i])

Handle division by zero:

```
select
wl,
COALESCE(lead(wl,1) over (order by wl) - wl) /
nullif((lead(ref,1) over (order by wl) - ref),0),0) as reflectance
from wa
order by wl
```

Comment: Some of my values are divided by zero, So it is giving error like thisERROR:  division by zero
********** Error **********

ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
,I want to use case statement if anything division by zero put 0 in that place and others put value. How to insert case in this query